# Objective C : How do i access a class declared inside another class in my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate

Here is my situation :

```
BaseClass.m file 

#import “BaseClass.h”

@class ClassOne 

@interface ClassOne {
  //Some properties
}

@end 

@implementation ClassOne

//Some methods

@end 



@implementation BaseClass 

//Some props and methods here
@end
```

I wanna access ClassOne in my AppDelegate. Since there are no header files for ClassOne I am unable to access properties of ClassOne in AppDelegate.
How do I achieve the same?

Comment: I do not understand why people are downvoting without giving proper reason. Stackoverflow needs to check this kinda behaviour.

Comment: I agree, that is behaviour very very very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Import  `"BaseClass.h"` file in `appDelegate` file.
- Write `ClassOne` interface in `BaseClass.h`

Comment: The answer is simple and helpful. People who downvote should learn from this !!

Comment: Thanks @Sangram !!

Answer (score 1):

Even many does not know it, there is no relationship between imports and interfaces. Importing is just text including without semantic information.

So put the interface of the class into a header file and import that header file, wherever you need it. You can add it into an existing header file or create a new one. (You can have as many header files as you want to.)

Comment: Yes this was helpful. Thanks